# Setting up includepaths for node-sass in webpack config

Tags: webpack, sass, sass-loader

Include paths not working when added to webpack config(or I am doing it wrong). I've tired two different methods.

I get the following error:

```
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @import "config.scss";
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
```

src/home/myfile.scss

```
@import "config.scss";
...
```

src/assets/sass/config.scss

```
$config_value: 3;
...
```

/webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
       ...plugins
    ],
    entry: {
        'styles.min': glob.sync("./src/**/*.scss"),
        'scripts.min': glob.sync("./src/**/*.js"),
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + `/dist/`,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use:[
                   ...loaders
                    // Compiles Sass to CSS
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader",
                        options: {
                          sassOptions: {
                            includePaths: [
                                "./src/assets/sass/", 
                                path.resolve(__dirname, "src/assets/sass")
                            ],
                          },
                        },
                      },
                    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo. "src/assests/sass" should be src/assets/sass

```
options: {
    sassOptions: {
      includePaths: [
          "./src/assets/sass/"
      ],
    },
},
```

Comment: Thanks, i've updated that but it still is not working.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).